# Need To Add Internationalization To The Root Path - Ruby on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, routes, rails-routing, i18n-gem

I want my routes to have the format /locale/route instead of /route?locale=en, etc.

I have the following in application_controller.rb

```
before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

  private
    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = (params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?) || cookies[:locale] || 'en'
      cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale.to_s
    end
```

I have this in routes.rb

```
scope "/:locale" do
  all my routes except for the root
end
```

I have the following code for the root path outside of the scope statement.  When I had these in the scope statement it set the locale to 404 and did not find a locale file for 404.

```
match '/:locale' => 'landing#index'
root            to: 'landing#index'
```

Here is the code in my heading view where people can change the language:

```
<p class="locale-line"><span class="english-link"><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %></span><%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :french}", locale: "fr" %></p>
```

Here is the code for a link using an image that returns to the root path:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("menu-home.jpg", alt: "My Home Page"), root_path %>

<%= link_to image_tag("menu-home.jpg", alt: "My Home Page"), root_url %>
```

I am able to successfully get the routes within the scope statement to display the routes as desired.  When a person initially displays the website and they click either language link at the top of the page the root path displays with /locale.  However my root path does not work like I want with the image tag.  Both examples display the root path with /?locale=en or /?locale=fr.

I have checked guides.rubyonrails.org and edgeguides.rubyonrails.org but did not find any examples of how to code the link_to statement for the root path where it will display the locale with format /locale.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have something like `Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.locale` in application.rb?

Comment: And I think you could add `root to: 'landing#index'` to the scope statement and `match '/' => "landing#index", locale: 'en'` outside this scope statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in `routes.rb`

```
match '/:locale' => 'landing#index', :as => 'locale_root'
```

And then link to it like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("menu-home.jpg"), locale_root_path %>
```

Or you may need to do

```
<%= link_to image_tag("menu-home.jpg"), locale_root_path(:locale => I18n.locale) %>
```

(I removed the `alt` param just to save space so that everything fits in the page.)

Comment: Jeremy, I changed the route as you suggested.  I changed the link_to statement to the first example.  The route format is working like the other routes.  Thanks so much for your help.